# How to get moved ID and replaced ID in jquery sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Im using jQuery sortable. I want to be able to get the ID for the item moved and the ID for the item it replaced. So far I am able to get the ID for the moved element but not the element it replaced.

My code is:

```
$(function () {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            var moved = ui.item,
                replaced = ui.item.prev();

            // if replaced.length === 0 then the item has been pushed to the top of the list
            // in this case we need the .next() sibling
            if (replaced.length == 0) {
                replaced = ui.item.next();
            }

            alert("moved ID:" + moved.attr("id"), "replaced ID:" + replaced.attr("id"));
        }
    });
});
```

How do I get back both the ID for the element being replaced and the element that was moved?

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kevinabraham/7rbv20yd/7/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it works, you are just calling alert with wrong arguments; replace it with `console.log` or concatenate the strings like this:

```
alert("moved ID:" + moved.attr("id") + "replaced ID:" + replaced.attr("id"));
```

(I replaced `,` with `+`)